# Error inflating class FontTextView by Yalantis

Tags: android, xml

Im trying to use an Android component I found on [Github](https://github.com/Yalantis/FlipViewPager.Draco). Using the sample project inside the repository I integrated the component into my app but everytime I run it I get the error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView`. This FontTextView has been used in the sample project which runs just fine. Im not sure what im doing wrong as I have also copied and pasted their layouts. I thought my images were the problem but I used the original pictures used in the sample application and it still crashed.

Here is the text from my logcat:

```
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                    at cc.tungait.voiture.activities.MainActivity$CarsAdapter.getPage(MainActivity.java:117)
                                                                    at com.yalantis.flipviewpager.adapter.BaseFlipAdapter$MergeAdapter.getView(BaseFlipAdapter.java:124)
                                                                    at com.yalantis.flipviewpager.view.FlipViewPager.setAdapter(FlipViewPager.java:468)
                                                                    at com.yalantis.flipviewpager.adapter.BaseFlipAdapter.getView(BaseFlipAdapter.java:72)`
```

The XML is exactly what's in the sample project:

`

```
<com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
    style="@style/TextView.Nickname"
    android:id="@+id/nickname" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/nickname"
    android:id="@+id/interestsPrimary"
    style="@style/LinearLayout.Interests">

    <com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
        style="@style/TextView.Interest"
        android:id="@+id/interest_1" />

    <com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
        style="@style/TextView.Interest"
        android:id="@+id/interest_2" />

    <com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
        style="@style/TextView.Interest"
        android:id="@+id/interest_3" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/interestsPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/interestsSecondary"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    style="@style/LinearLayout.Interests">

    <com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/interest_4"
        style="@style/TextView.Interest" />

    <com.yalantis.flip.sample.views.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/interest_5"
        style="@style/TextView.Interest" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Show us your XML where you are inflating FontTextView

Comment: Check your package name of FontTextView in your XML

Comment: Did you add in your build.grade     compile 'com.yalantis:flipviewpager:1.0.0'

Comment: Have you added the compile file in your Gradle compile 'com.yalantis:flipviewpager:1.0.0'

Comment: Yes I added that compile statement. @RakshitNawani what do u mean by check the package? Isnt it that Im using that library so that component s from that library?

Comment: You have a Class name "FontTextView" copy its package name and paste it in your XML file where you are using the XML like package_name.FontTextView Try it and let me know

Comment: post your code that uses this xml layout

Comment: I was using the same code as the project's code which just involved inflating the view with a custom adapter but it has been solved thanks @bryanc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the package name of your **FontTextView** in your XML **like package_name.FontTextView**.

Like below

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_below="@+id/interestsPrimary"
android:id="@+id/interestsSecondary"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
style="@style/LinearLayout.Interests">

<package_name.FontTextView
    android:id="@+id/interest_4"
    style="@style/TextView.Interest" />

<package_name.FontTextView
    android:id="@+id/interest_5"
    style="@style/TextView.Interest" />
```

You have to match the same package name as in your Project.
Try it and let me know if it worked for you

Comment: Worked 100%!! thanks alot. just had problems with getting the colour but that easily solvable

Comment: Happy to help, Cheers, Happy Coding